# how to get the jquery last state

Tags: jquery

Hi I am using the jquery image slider from http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/. this works perfectly but after postback the slider starts from 0. how to remember the last state after postbacks? here is the live demo http://sampath.ind.in

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#slidebox").jCarouselLite({
    vertical: false,
    hoverPause: true,
    btnPrev: ".previous",
    btnNext: ".next",
    visible: 3,
    circular: false,
    start: 0,
    scroll: 1,
    speed: 300
});
```

});

Comment: You can try saving it in a cookie or localStorage, another more solid option (but more bandwidth expensive) is to ajax call a PHP page to update a session variable, and use that.

Comment: @Rikudo could you please provide me some examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `afterEnd` callback to store the current state in a cookie or local storage and start from there if this key is present.

This should set a cookie (lastPosition), that you can use later:

```
$(...).jCarouselLite({
  ...
  afterEnd:function(e){$.cookie('lastPosition', e.first().index());}
  ...
});
```

To start with a predefined position you would do something like this:

```
$(...).jCarouselLite({
  ...
  start: parseInt($.cookie('lastPosition'),10) || 0
  ...
});
```

To set/retrieve cookies you can use this library: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie. This is not tested code, but it should give you a basic idea.

Comment: i am a novice regarding jquery. could you please tell me how to get the current state ans store it in cookie. i am coding with asp.net.

Comment: thanks for the info, so after every click we register the position in cookie?

Comment: more or less right. afterEnd is triggered when the animation ends. you can use beforeStart if you want to set it when the user clicks the button. See callback demo @ http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#demo

Comment: yes definitely that makes sense but how do i get that 3 visible elements? could you please explain?

Comment: e in the callback functions contains the visible elements. I assumed that you simply want to start with the left one, therefor e.first() (the first one of those three) .index() (the index position within all lis

Comment: topek, thanks a lot for your patience. if you check my site http://sampath.ind.in, if you scroll by one element and click on any of the front, back, detail which will cause postback. i want the same elements to be visible after postback. but currently after postback it simply starts from first element.

Comment: If I'm looking at the right code, you did not include any of my suggestions in the page, or did you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3970/discussion-between-topek-and-sam)

Comment: topek, the problem why it is not working in internet explorer and safari is because of that frames you mentioned.